# How to use sequelize-auto to import models from another database

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I'd like to import the models from another database to my local project. I found that sequelize-auto could make things a lot easier than creating the models from scratch.

However, when I try to use the CLI command it gives me this error:

```
bash: sequelize-auto: command not found
```

I just followed the documentation where it says I can execute this:

`sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models]`

I also found a GUI for sequelize-auto. however, I am confused about how to make it work and use it. Maybe someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

had to add npx `npx sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models]`